# How to reference object when add view by programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have JSON data and would like to add them to EditText

JSON

```
{
   "Data":[
       {
         "Name":"benz",
         "Display":"slk200",
         "Value":"1"
      },
      {
         "Name":"bmw",
         "Display":"z4",
         "Value":"2"
      },
      {
         "Name":"toyota",
         "Display":"supra",
         "Value":"3"
      },
      {
         "Name":"honda",
         "Display":"civic",
         "Value":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

Java

```
LinearLayout placeHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.place_holder);
for (Data f : dataList) {
    EditText ed = new EditText(context);
    ed.setHint(f.display);
    placeHolder.addView(ed);
}
```

If I would like to reference the EditText object after click some button
What should I do?

Comment: Let me understand you better. Do you have a button that, when the user clicks there you will change something in some edittext, right? Do you have the json parser?

Comment: Yes, I parse JSON to Class object and when click button I would like to change text in some edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) inherits from TextView, which inherits from [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). This means, you can use the [`view.setId(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) to assign an `id` to the dynamic `EditText` view.

You can then call `findViewById(EditText id you gave it)` to get the EditText view.

For example, assigning an id:

```
EditText ed = new EditText(context);
ed.setId(99);
```

And to reference the new EditText view:

```
EditText tmpEd = (EditText) findViewById(99);
tmpEd.setText("a test string");
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing Json request,

```
String jsonString;
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject dataJSON  = reader.getJSONObject("Data");
displayText = dataJSON.getString("Display");

EditText ed = new EditText(context);
ed.setHint(displayText );
```

Following links might b useful to u

1- [TutorailzPoint-JsonParsing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

2- [AndroidHive-Json](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

for the part on the button, you can implement an onClickListener.
If you have already created a button in your layout. 
Reference it with:

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.<buttonid>);
```

Then you can create an onClickListener for the button, which listens for a click.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.<edittextid>);
            //get records
            e1.setText(<next record>);
    }

});
```